# What is the difference between "RTCSdpTypeAnswer" and "RTCSdpTypePrAnswer"?

Tags: swift, webrtc

He||o

I am coding using Swift and WebRTC, I do not understand what is the difference between "RTCSdpTypeAnswer" and "RTCSdpTypePrAnswer" (enum RTCSdpType in RTCSessionDescription.h file)

I do not find the answer on internet, can someone help me please ?

(I got WebRTC using the "GoogleWebRTC" pod)

Comment: `pranswer` is an early-but-not-final answer, mostly for legacy hardware. It has poor web compat. You can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jib's comment:
pranswer is an early-but-not-final answer, mostly for legacy hardware. It has poor web compat. You can safely ignore it.